# Grouped Query Call

Tags: visualforce, soql, aggregate

I'd like to display a short table of Users and their Activities. I can get to the id but when trying to display the username I run into grouping issues or relationship issues.
Here's my class:

```
public with sharing class ActivityController {

public Summary[] Summaries { get; set; }

public ActivityController () {
    AggregateResult[] results = [
        SELECT CreatedBy.Name, Count(Id) Quantity FROM Event  where Role__c = 'KD US Rep' or  Role__c = 'KD US Mgr' GROUP BY CreatedBy.Name
    ];
    Summaries = new List<Summary>();
    for (AggregateResult ar : results) {
        Summaries.add(new Summary(ar));
    }
}

// wrapper class to hold aggregate data
public class Summary {
    public Integer Quantity { get; private set; }
    public String aName { get; private set; }

    public Summary(AggregateResult ar) {
        Quantity = (Integer) ar.get('Quantity');
        aName = (String) ar.get('CreatedBy.Name');
    }
}
```

}

Here's my page:

```
<apex:page controller="ActivityController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:repeat value="{!Summaries}" var="summary">
        {!summary.aName}: {!summary.Quantity}<br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:form>
```

Gives me error:

> Invalid field CreatedBy.Name for AggregateResult

How can I make a simple table of Users' Activities? thanks!

Comment: Seems I can aggregate by ID, but I don't want to display by id. Who would?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part answer and also somewhat of a commentary. First, `CreatedBy` is a polymorphic field similar to the `WhatId` or `WhoId` only it's a System Field that refers to a UserId. If I'm not mistaken, I recall reading once that all System Fields are polymorphic.

I see that you're running this on `Event` and not on `Task`. Events also have `OwnerId` as another field to use to possibly identify who the User is that created it and might be the user you're looking for. You might want to inquire whether the `CreatedBy` is also going to be the `Owner` as it's possible the Event was created by one user and ownership was then transferred or assigned to another user.

With all that said, you should be able to run a subquery on User to get the User name associate with either the CreatedBy or the Owner used in the `WHERE` clause of your query. Your query should then look something like this:

```
AggregateResult[] results = [
    SELECT Id, CreatedBy, OwnerId, Count(Id) Quantity (SELECT Id, Name from Users)
    FROM Event  WHERE Role__c = 'KD US Rep' or  Role__c = 'KD US Mgr'
 GROUP BY CreatedBy.Name];
```

I've never run a subquery like this using a GroupBy clause, so you may need to remove the GroupBy and sort these using other methods. You'll need to loop through these anyway to create a map of `CreatedBy` and the `CreatedBy.Name` and/or the OwnerId and Owner.Name which would be done something like below:

```
map<Id,AggregateResult>arMap = new map<Id,AggregateResult>(results);
list<User>UsRep = new list<User>();
list<AggregateResult>Rslt = new list<AggregateResult>();
map<Id,string>crtdId2Name = new map<Id,string>();
map<Id,string>ownId2Name = new map<Id,string>();

For(Id eId : arMap.keyset()){

   Event evt = arMap.get(eId);  // this may need to be AggregateResult instead of Event

   list<User>UsRep = evt.Users;

   For(User u:UsRep){
      If(u.Id = evt.CreatedBy){
         crtdId2Name.put(u.Id, u.Name);
      }else if(u.Id = evt.OwnerId) 
         ownId2Name.put(u.Id, u.Name);
      {        

   }

}
```

Note: This code has not been tested or debugged and is for example purposes only.

Comment: thanks, I used another solution but may need to reference this in the future

Comment: Took me a while to write it up with interruptions, so couldn't post it sooner. Glad you got something working.

Comment: this may still be helpful - a workflow solution might not always be applicable!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using another solution and grouping by another field I update via workflow.

Comment: hi jaw999 can you please post your solution